# Python exception

Tags: manjaro, python3

I am getting these errors when running for example lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings or compiling python applications.

I can see it is python related, but unsure on what steps are needed to resolve. 
installed Python default 3.5 (also have 2.7 installed)

OS Manjaro XFCE (Arch 64 based)

Can someone advise what the problem is please?

thanks

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/enum34-1.0.4-py3.5.egg/enum/__init__.py", line 371, in __getattr__
KeyError: '_convert'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings", line 33, in <module>
    lightdm_gtk_greeter_settings.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lightdm_gtk_greeter_settings/__init__.py", line 24, in main
    from gi.repository import Gtk
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gi/importer.py", line 115, in load_module
    dynamic_module = load_overrides(introspection_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gi/overrides/__init__.py", line 125, in load_overrides
    override_mod = importlib.import_module(override_package_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 26, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GObject
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gi/importer.py", line 115, in load_module
    dynamic_module = load_overrides(introspection_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gi/overrides/__init__.py", line 125, in load_overrides
    override_mod = importlib.import_module(override_package_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gi/overrides/GObject.py", line 31, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GLib
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gi/importer.py", line 115, in load_module
    dynamic_module = load_overrides(introspection_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gi/overrides/__init__.py", line 125, in load_overrides
    override_mod = importlib.import_module(override_package_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py", line 22, in <module>
    import signal
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/signal.py", line 8, in <module>
    _IntEnum._convert(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/enum34-1.0.4-py3.5.egg/enum/__init__.py", line 373, in __getattr__
AttributeError: _convert
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running this code against python 3.5 - however it appears enum only runs against 3.4 or earlier.  Try running against `/usr/bin/python2.7` interpreter. or an earlier Python 3 `<= 3.4`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am looking lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings and it is set to run as python3 as dictated by the the first line of the script. Changing to python2 causes an error "ImportError: No module named lightdm_gtk_greeter_settings". I believe this is a configuration setup problem with python as it seems to be effecting more than just one application.

Comment: This shows 3.5 supporting enum https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/enum.html#enum.Enum

Answer (score 0):

With some excellent help from The-Compiler on #python at freenode it is now fixed.

```
cd /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages; pacman -Qo * 2>&1 | grep '^error:'
```

Remove all packages listed from site-packages directory.